# Passing map name as argument in nested each loop

Tags: sass

Is it possible to pass map names as argument in nested each loop?

For example, we have the following:

```
$colorsets: () !default;
$colorsets: map-merge(
  (
    "greys": "get-gray",
    "reds": "get-red"
  ),
  $colorsets
);

@each $colorset, $value in $colorsets {
    /* #{$colorset} #{$value} */
    @each $color, $value in $colorset {
        /* #{$color} #{$value} */
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

and where `greys` and `reds` are also maps with some colors.

My goal here is to collect the map name from the first loop and pass it as argument to the second loop. The problem is that compiler takes the variable as text, not as a map!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The solution was to put map varables as values in main `$colorsets` map, think like an array of maps:

```
$colorsets: () !default;
$colorsets: map-merge(
   (
       0:  $greys,
       1:  $reds // and so on
   ),
   $colorsets
);
```

Obviously, this should come after all defined color maps. And, the nested loops come like this:

```
    @each $index, $colorset in $colorsets {
        /* #{$index} */
        @each $color-name, $color in $colorset {
            /* #{$color-name} #{$color} */
            // do stuff here
        }
    }
```

Hope someone will find this useful.